# Undefined subroutine &package::subroutine called at line <of script>

Tags: perl, package, undefined

I am debugging this script at work - the boss says that is used to work on Solaris, but since they switched over to linux, it stopped working. I had to rewrite it with strict and warnings . 
When I run it I get error:

```
Undefined subroutine &Logging::openLog called at /path/to/script line 27
```

here is script (well part of it)

```
 1  #!/usr/local/bin/perl
 2
 3  unshift @INC, "/production/fo/lib";
 4  use strict;
 5  use warnings;
 6  use Sys::Hostname;
 7  use Getopt::Long qw(:config bundling auto_version);
 8  use File::Path;
 9
10  require "dbconfig2.pl";
11  require "logging2.pl";
12  require "hpov.pl";
13
14  # global variables
15  my $parseDate   = "";
16  my @fileList    = "";
17  my @transList   = "";
18  my $mLogDate    = "";
19  my $lHost                       = hostname;
20  my $corefiles_dir="/production/log/corefiles";
21  my $default_Threshold=90;
22
23  # do stuff
24
25  parseOptions();
26  Dbconfig::readconfigFile("$config");
27  Logging::openLog("$Dbconfig::prefs{logFile}","overwrite");
28  # msglog actions  TODO logs, compress only, data files
29          my $check_shdw=`ls -l /etc/motd | awk '{print \$11}' | grep 'motd.shdw'`; #Check if hostname is shadow
30          $check_shdw =~ y/\n//d; #remove new line if any
31  if ( $check_shdw eq "motd.shdw" )
32  {
33          Logging::printLog("INFO","Enviroment is Shadow, triggering core files compressing");
34          if (is_folder_empty($corefiles_dir)) {
35              print "Corefile Directory is EMPTY......! \n";
36          }
37          else {
38          gzip_corefiles() ; #Execute compress core files
39          }
40  }
41
```

The script uses require statements to I guess call upon the routines that the script creator built. 
For the purpsoe of this script - the dbconfig just slurps in a config file and breaks them down into values. 
like the "$Dbconfig::prefs{logFile}" equals a logfile location  /prod/logs/script.log - that's it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

package Dbconfig;
#use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;

%prefs          = "";
@$dbPrefs       = "";
$raiseError     = 0;
%startupItem    = "";

# readconfigFile(file) - read in a configuration file.
sub readconfigFile { 
    my $file = shift;
    if ( ! -e $file ) {
        $errorTxt   = "Error: $file does not exist.\n";
        $raiseError = 1;
    }
# read in the cfg variables
   open(CFGFILE,"<","$file") or die "Cannot open $file for reading: $!\n";
   while(<CFGFILE>) {
    chomp;    # kill newlines
    s/#.*//;  # ignore comments
    s/^\s+//; # ignore leading whitespace
    s/\s+$//; # ignore trailing whitespace
    next unless length;
    my($var,$value) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $_, 2);
    $prefs{$var} = $value;
   }
   close(CFGFILE);
}
```

Then there is this logging package. In line 27 of the script (where the error comes in) i see an "overwrite" invocation, but don't see anything referenceing overwrite in the logging.pl package - but not really sure if it matters. the parent script does not seem to write to any log file. I am not even  sure if the filehandle LOGFILE is gtting created.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

 package Logging;

use File::Copy;
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $timestamp = "";
my $filestamp = "";

# openLog(logfile name) - opens a log file
sub openLog {
    my $file   = shift;
    my $rotate = shift;
 # force a rotation if it exists.
    if ( -e $file && $rotate eq "rotate" ) {
        print "Warning: $file exists.  Rotating.\n";
        rotateLog($file);
    }
    getTime(); 
    open(LOGFILE,">","$file") or warn "Error: Cannot open $file for writing: $!\n";
    print LOGFILE "[$timestamp] - Normal - Opening log for $file.\n"; 
}
# rotateLog(log file) - rotate a log.
sub rotateLog {
    my $file = shift;
    getTime();
    openLog("$file");
    print LOGFILE "[$timestamp] - Warning - Rotating $file to $file.$filestamp.log";
    closeLog($file);
    move($file,$file-"$filestamp.log");
    openLog($file);
}
time() - grab timestamp for the log.
sub getTime {
    undef $timestamp;
    undef $filestamp;
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = (localtime(time))[0,1,2,3,4,5];
    $sec    = sprintf("%02d",$sec);
    $min    = sprintf("%02d",$min);
    $hour   = sprintf("%02d",$hour);
    $mday   = sprintf("%02d",$mday);
    $year   = sprintf("%04d",$year +1900);
    $mon    = sprintf("%02d",$mon +1);
    $timestamp  = "$mon-$mday-$year $hour:$min:$sec";
    $filestamp  = "$year$mon$mday$hour$min$sec";
}
```

just wondering - is there a problem with logging.pl calling something from dbconfig.pl in line 27?  Like can one module call a value fron another module?  besides using strict and warnings, and alot of print statements I do not know what my next debugging
 step is.  I have not idea how to check and see that the LOGFILE filehandle is getting created - if it does not error out, I can only suppose that it is. Like is there something extra I have to do to get the modules talking to each other?

I am not a scripting king - just the only guy in my row who can even begin to understand this stuff.

Comment: "just wondering - is there a problem with logging.pl calling something from dbconfig.pl in line 27?" Well, does it work if you call the dbconfig thing in main, store it into a string and call logging with that?

Comment: You should know that `openLog` does not do what it seems to do. It tries to protect the old log if it exists (and the user told it to), but then it calls `rotateLog`, which calls `openLog` again, truncates the file, and then backs up the truncated log. Much of this code would be better handled by modules, such as a module to handle logfiles, reading/writing config files, creating a timestamp...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will effect things but ....

1) Packages need to return true, normal procedure is to end the file with the line:

```
1;
```

to ensure that.

2) Theres a comment in the logger package without the leading # which would cause compilation failure:

```
time() - grab timestamp for the log.
```

3) This line:

```
unshift @INC, "/production/fo/lib";
```

is adding the directory to search path for modules, make sure your logging2.pl file is actually in that location (it propably is otherwise you would get different errors, but worth a double check)

Comment: Yeah there is a 1 at the bottom of the script (i was wonder why it was there) the lack of a comment is my fault (it is there in the original code) and the logging2.pl file is in the correct path. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

That looks all OK then.

For some reason although require "logging2.pl" works (there'd be an error if not) the sub-routines in it aren't loaded and available. Unlike the load of DBconfig2.pl which works OK (otherwise the call to Dbconfig::readconfigFile() would fail first).

Only difference I can see is the leading space on the package command in Logging2.pl, don't think that would matter though.

Could try calling openLog without the package prefix (Logging::) to see if its been loading into main from some reason and print the contents of %INC after the require statements to make sure its been loaded correctly?